# How to upload multiple file and move into folder in php?

Tags: php

code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['img_url']['name']))
        {
            for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['img_url']['name']); $i++) 
            {
                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['img_url']['tmp_name'][$i];    
                if ($tmpFilePath != "")
                {    
                    $path = "../images/hotel_images/";   
                    $name = $_FILES['img_url']['name'][$i];
                    $size = $_FILES['img_url']['size'][$i];
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    $file= time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
                    $info = pathinfo($file);
                    $filename = $file.".".$ext;
                    $filepath_upload = $path.$filename;
                    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
                    {
                        $j2 = $i+1;
                        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Sorry, ".$j2." Image files Extension .".$ext." are not Uploaded & Other files Uploaded Successfully <br/>.</div>" ;
                    }
                    else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_url']['tmp_name'][$i], $filepath_upload)) 
                    {
                        $banner_image_source_file = $filepath_upload;
                        $banner_image_save_file = $filepath_upload;
                        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($banner_image_source_file);
                        $img_url_name.=$filename."|";
                    }
                }
                $filepath = rtrim($img_url_name, '|');  
            }
            if(!empty($filepath))
            {
                $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `hotel`(`img_url`, `status`) VALUES ('".$filepath."')");
                if($query)
                {
                    $msg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Hotel Record Added Successfully</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Unbale to Add Hotel Record Please Try Again !!!</div>";
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Unable to Add Please Try Again !! </div>";
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Unable to Add Please Try Again !! </div>";
        } 
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add-hotel-form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="hotel">Upload Hotel Images</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_hotel_img1" name="img_url[]" multiple>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="room">Upload Room Images</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_room_img1" name="img_url2[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the following code I have create a simple form where I have two `input field type='file'` where I am able to upload only first one i.e. `<label for="hotel">Upload Hotel Images</label>` and move into the folder successfully but I also want to upload and move second input field i.e. `<label for="room">Upload Room Images</label>`. I don't have any idea about this. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you need to write your code for img_url2 field also from here if(isset($_FILES['img_url2']['name'])) to boottom

Answer (score 0):

Your Room Image input is called `img_url2`, which you never interact with in code.

For best practice, move the bulk of your PHP code into a file upload function, then call it once with `img_url` $_FILE input, and once with `img_url2`.

Example:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", true);

function uploadFile($file, $path)
{
    $img_url_name = "";

    if(is_array($file) && isset($file['name']) && isset($file['tmp_name']) && isset($file['size']))
    {
        $tmpFilePath = isset($file['tmp_name'][0]) ? $file['tmp_name'][0] : "";
        $name = isset($file['name'][0]) ? $file['name'][0] : "";

        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
        $file = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
        $filename = $file.".".$ext;
        $filepath_upload = $path.$filename;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
        {
            return "<div class='alert alert-success'>Sorry, ".$name." Image files Extension .".$ext." are not Uploaded & Other files Uploaded Successfully <br/>.</div>" ;
        }
        else if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filepath_upload))
        {
            $img_url_name .= $filename."|";
        }

        $filepath = rtrim($img_url_name, '|');

        if(!empty($filepath))
        {
            if(!isset($con))
            {
                global $con;
            }

            $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `hotel`(`img_url`, `room_url`) VALUES ('".$filename."','".$filepath."')");
            if($query)
            {
                return "<div class='alert alert-success'>Hotel Record Added Successfully</div>";
            }
        }
    }

    return "<div class='alert alert-success'>Unable to Add Please Try Again !! </div>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_FILES['img_url']['name']))
    {
        echo uploadFile($_FILES['img_url'], "../images/hotel_images/");
    }
    if(isset($_FILES['img_url2']['name']))
    {
        echo uploadFile($_FILES['img_url2'], "../images/room_img/");
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add-hotel-form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="hotel">Upload Hotel Images</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_hotel_img1" name="img_url" multiple>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="room">Upload Room Images</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_room_img1" name="img_url2" multiple>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to move `room images` into `images/room_img` and insert its value and my query should be look like `insert into hotel(`img_url`,`room_url`)values('".$filepath.",'".$filepath2."'')` @Gary Thomas.

Comment: I've updated my answer above. The hotel and room images now store in different paths. As for the SQL, I'm not sure what values you wanted img_url and room_url to be, but I feel like I've done the hard part, you should be able to insert the correct values from here :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `FormData()` to upload multiple images from multiple fields. Please take a look at this code:

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add-hotel-form">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="hotel">Upload Hotel Images</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_hotel_img1" name="img_url" multiple>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="room">Upload Room Images</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="upload_room_img2" name="img_url2" multiple>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myfunction();">
    </form>
</body>

<script>
function myfunction(){

    var form_data = new FormData();

    var image = document.getElementById('upload_hotel_img1').files.length;
    var images = document.getElementById('upload_room_img2').files.length;

    for (var x = 0; x < image; x++) {
        form_data.append("image", document.getElementById('upload_hotel_img1').files[x]);
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < images; x++) {
        form_data.append("images[]", document.getElementById('upload_room_img2').files[x]);
    }
}
</script>
```

We can retrieve these images in the backend using the follwing : `$_FILES["image"]['name']` and `$_FILES["images"]['name']` respectively.